# What is this device connected to my cold water pipe?

Tags: plumbing

Our house has an attached greenhouse; under the sink there is a device connected to the cold water supply that then goes into the slab.   There is a floor drain in the slab, so it's possible it connects there.   What is the device called, what is its purpose?

[image: Under sink plumbing]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suspicion coupled with an image search says yes, it's (almost certainly) a **[trap primer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_primer)** for the floor drain. Makes sure the floor drain trap does not dry out when disused and allow sewer gas to vent into the space.

Comment: Thanks!   Never heard or them before.   Also reminds me that in the off-season when the water is off, I may want to add a little antifreeze to that trap since we don't heat the greenhouse.